# python requests.text to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests

I have the below code, where I am trying to get the data from https://www.quandl.com/data/TSE/documentation/metadata. (Trying to get the **Download detailed data**)

```
for page_number in range(1, 5):
    link = r'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.csv?database_code=TSE&per_page=100&sort_by=id&page=' + str(page_number)
    r = requests.get(link, stream=True).text
    print(r)
    # How to put the results in a dataframe?
```

However, I have trouble putting the results in a dataframe / saving it in a SQLite database. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Pandas to read this data directly:

```
import pandas as pd

url = ("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.csv?"
       "database_code=TSE&per_page=100&sort_by=id&page={0}")
[pd.read_csv(url.format(page_number)) for page_number in range(1, 5)]
```

To read from response you can use `StringIO`:

```
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm curious about something. The last page on the website seems to be 40. So if I set the loop to be `for page_number in range(1, 50)` instead, it seems to produce an error at the end. Is there a way to better handle this error?

Comment: With requests you can check status code (`r.status_code` == 200). With `read_csv` I am not sure.

Comment: Its alright. I tried `if r == ''` then `break` and it works. :)

Comment: The first option didn't work for me, but the StringIO solution did. Thanks!